# warning: compiler may be ABI-incompatible with PyTorch, but only with one specific project

Tags: linux, python, ubuntu-14.04, gcc, anaconda

I have a conda environment with pytorch 1.1.0 installed, compatible with python 3.6.8 and cuda10.0.

I ran some simple examples of pytorch with this environment - everything seems to work well.

I pulled a project from github, and I get the following warning
(I don't get this warning with the code examples I ran):

> Your compiler (c++) may be ABI-incompatible with PyTorch!

I tried to ignore the warning and let the code run, but I get a segmentation fault.
I wanted to understand the issue and solve it, I started with verifying the gcc version:

running the command: 
`gcc --version` I get gcc 4.8.4

but through python `print(sys.version)` it prints

> [GCC 7.3.0]

why is there a difference?
and if there's a difference - why the project I pulled from github shows the warning and my example code does not?

I want to avoid upgrading gcc because I need to have compatible to my tensorflow environments as well.

thanks

Comment: This looks more like a question for StackOverflow.